# JFrog Artifactory AQL

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am currently trying to query Artifactory for specific artifacts related to a core project. All artifacts will be prefixed with a project tag. Example: "proj1-core". I use Artifactory aql to query artifacts using **name** attribute.

Now I also have a need to query specific type of artifacts - **maven, pypi, npm, docker**. I am aware of **type** attribute of artifact domain, but it is not which defines these types. I have seen types have specific properties. Example - npm.*, pypi.*, docker.*.

But for maven it has artifact.* and not for others. I am trying to find a common property which gives the **type** of the artifact.

Please let me know of any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Artifactory query language does not have a field which includes the package type.
You can assume the package type from the repository, which will cover most cases (not including Generic repositories or generic artifacts which are deployed to typed repositories).